# Excel Conditional loop Call range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have multiple rows in an excel sheet. I have to check every single row C:E and see if a date changed in each row.
this is the code.
Is there a way to create a loop and not repete the code under Exec_Conditional ?
I AM NEW TO EXCEL CONDITIONAL THANK YOU!

```
Sub Exec_Conditional()
    Call Conditional(Range("C5:E5"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C6:E6"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C7:E7"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C8:E8"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C9:E9"))
    Call Conditional(Range("C10:E10"))

End Sub
Sub Conditional(RangeToPerform As Range)

    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.Delete
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(RangeToPerform.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority: 
RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlUnique
    With RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844: .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic: .Color = 13551615: .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    RangeToPerform.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the expected result of applying a conditional format to it? It looks to me that this could be done without VBA using a single conditional format created in the application.

Comment: Hi, different dates in multiple rows. For example in the first row 02/02/2022 should be highlighted in red

  C D E
    
    
5  01/01/2022 01/01/2022 02/02/2022
6  02/02/2022 02/01/2022 02/02/2022
7  01/01/2022 01/01/2022 02/02/2022
8  01/01/2022 01/01/2022 02/02/2022
9  02/02/2022 02/01/2022 02/02/2022
10  02/02/2022 02/01/2022 02/02/2022

Comment: OK, but why do you need to create a separate format condition for each row of your data? Why not create a single condition for the whole range?

Comment: sure, but I should loop through all the rows and apply the same condition right?

Comment: Instead of applying the condition to C5:E5, C6:E6, ... C10:E10, you could apply it to C5:E10. You *could* loop through the range and I'll post an answer showing how, but it doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the range with a `For` loop:

```
Sub Exec_Conditional()
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In Range("C5:E10").Rows
      Conditional row ' equivalent to Call Conditional(row)
    Next row
End Sub
```

However, it looks to me like you should be able to solve the problem without looping by applying a format condition to the whole range. If your data is 1000 rows long, it's unlikely that you want or need 1000 conditions.